# Network connectivity lost when using NordVPN Kill Switch

Tags: linux, systemd, nordvpn

I'm using NordVPN with the Kill Switch feature enabled.

If my computer does not shut down gracefully, the file `/etc/resolv.conf` is set immutable, and any future attempts to resolve names fail.

Sometimes, even without an unclean shutdown, when running `ping` as `root`, I see:

> ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted

How do I use the kill switch and have uninterrupted connectivity?

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the `nordvpnd` service solves the connectivity issue.

Here's how to do it automatically:

Create `/etc/systemd/system/nordvpnd-restart-after-network-online.service`:

```
# Prevent immutable /etc/resolv.conf
# https://forum.manjaro.org/t/internet-blocked-by-nordvpn-killswitch/108413
# https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=246004

# If using NetworkManager, requires NetworkManager-wait-online.service to be started
# https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/

[Unit]
Description=restart nordvpnd after network online
After=NetworkManager-wait-online.service
# Uncomment if using networkd, and comment previous line
; Before=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl restart nordvpnd

[Install]
WantedBy=NetworkManager-wait-online.service
# Uncomment if using networkd, and comment previous line
; WantedBy=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

Enable both required services:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service nordvpnd-restart-after-network-online.service
```

Now, immediately after `NetworkManager` says it's online, the `nordvpnd` service will be automatically restarted.

Answer (score 1):

The [solution by Tom Hale](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/562582/377345) didn't work for me, using the `nordvpnd` daemon. (By the way, I don't know how to use the killswitch with NetworkManager, since there doesn't seems to be any option for that?)

What I did is adding the following script `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99restart_nordvpnd.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    resume)
        /usr/bin/systemctl restart nordvpnd
        ;;
esac
```

After making it executable, the nordvpn daemon is automatically restarted when the compouter resumes from suspend.

If this doesn't work, you may try a slightly different script:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
        pre)
                echo "$(date): $1" >> /tmp/nordvpn/suspend.txt
                /usr/bin/systemctl restart nordvpnd
                ;;
        post)
                echo "$(date): $1" >> /tmp/nordvpn/suspend.txt
                ;;
esac
```

(Note that the "echo" lines are completely optional. I used them for debugging)

This file must be put in a different location:

```
/lib/systemd/system-sleep/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the only thing that worked for me was disabling the killswitch.

What happens is when your computer goes to sleep it loses connectivity and the killswitch will deny all connectivity because you are not connected to the VPN. It won't even let you reconnect without disabling the killswitch.

The only solution seem to be to disable the killswitch momentarily to restablish the connection and then re-enabling the killswitch.